# Brainstorming methods to save stylesheet across webpages in static site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I have a static website that I implemented a simple stylesheet swapping script in order to change the page's color between white and black.

```
<div class="container">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i=1;
    function styleSheet(){
        if(i%2==0){
            swapper('css/main.css');            
        }
        else{
            swapper('css/stylesheetalternate.css');             
        }
        i++;
    }
</script>
<br>
<button onclick="styleSheet()">Click me</button>
<script>
    function swapper(select_sheet){
        document.getElementById('swapper').setAttribute('href', select_sheet);
    }
</script>
```

At the moment if a user switches the webpage from the default css (white) to a black theme, when they go to a different page, the webpage will load the default css rather than keeping the alternate css theme that they chose on the previous page. Is there any possible way to allow a user who chooses a specific stylesheet to keep that stylesheet among all other pages in my website?

I have a static site so I'm not sure if there's any methods to do this via html/css/javascript/jquery.

Comment: You can try looking at Javascript local storage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: you need to store the selected stylesheet info somewhere... it can be in a cookie/web storage(sessionStorage/localStorate)

Comment: You could use [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) ;)

Comment: What is the advantage (or disadvantage) of using HTML5 webstorage vs cookies? I've never used either before so just wondering if either would be better overall or if there is no difference between the two